# geotiff.dll is missing when calling gdal command

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, error, gdalwarp

I recently installed gdal for windows using OSGeo4W 64 bit. When trying to call gadal commands like gdalwarp from commandline I encounter with this error:[image]

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Do you run the command from the OSGeo4W Shell window that you can open from the Windows start menu?

Comment: No, I tried it now and it is working. but I want to do it in cmd windows

Comment: Have a look at the OSGeo4W.bat file that is in your OSGeo4W installation directory. That is setting all the environmental variable right and you must do the same. But OSGeo4W shell is just a cmd window with a different title.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I need to call it from python using os.system so I want to make it work at cmd

Comment: The issue is still in the paths.